# Is it possible to set button visible only in DEBUG mode?

Tags: android

I need to add a button to menu navigation at the sidebar of my app, but I don't really understand how to make it right. It should be visible only when app is in a DEBUG mode/apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please write button visiblity method like below code

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        write you button visiblity code.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

yes use something like this.

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
   button.visibility = View.GONE
}
```